# Reports: Accounts with Opportunities

Tags: reporting, custom-reports, sales

I am trying to build a report in Salesforce. I am using the Accounts report type. For context, I have 5 Accounts and each Account has 5 Opportunities. If one of the Opportunities contains the word 'EXCLUDE' in the Opportunity Name, I would like to ensure the Account the Opportunity is related to is NOT displayed in the report. Is this possible to do? If so, can you please provide some guidance on how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Roll-up summery field on Account Like below which can be used  as a report filter. You can modify the filter according to your need

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Avijit. This works great!